Is there a way to turn an IN statement into an easily selectable list?
If I have a query as this:
select column1
from table 1
where column2 in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3'...etc)

Is there anyway to turn the in statement values into a selectable list? Often times I'll pull all values or only half the values in a rather large list. Was wondering if there's an easier way to do this. I use DBeaver CE if that matters at all.
I've tried to use IN (:Value1), but I think I'm misunderstanding this functionality. It seems close as it prompts the user to enter a value, but would be nice if it was just a dropdown list to select from.

How many values you plan to have in the IN criteria ? Did you think of putting them in a table.

It sounds like you want a query like the one in this meaningless question

It is possible using Snowsight webui. You can create filters with static lists or dynamic lists from a table. Refer to this documentation for creating filters. I'm not sure if it is feasible in Datagrip or Beaver. It is annoying to type or paste values.



